# How to count the repetitive customers in Tableau?

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, dashboard

[How to count the repetitive customers?][1]

```
Client_ID | Created_At(Date Stamp)
1         | 27-07-2020  10:30:08
2         | 04-10-2020  09:20:21
3         | 28-07-2020  18:55:25
1         | 28-07-2020  06:45:14
```

Comment: Hi.  How do you want your output?  In your example do you want to filter out cilent_id - 1 only?

Answer (score 0):

Include a calculated field

```
{FIXED [client_id]: COUNT([client_id])}>1
```

`TRUE` will indicate a returning customer while `FALSE` indicate one time customer only.

[image]

data used

[image]

**NOTE** `COUNT([client_id]) > 1` will also do the similar job, but will require that client_id is added in the view.  `FIXED` will eliminate the need of adding `client-id` in the view.